# visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio

How many unloaded/unavailable projects can be in a solution? I have a single solution with a bunch of test projects and I unload/load them as needed.

Comment: More than you'll have patience to add them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the existing answers, note that you can create your own build configurations (the drop down with Debug/Release in it), and choose not to build some of your projects - this is quicker than loading/unloading, and has the advantage of also not screwing with your file/project references.

Also note that if you group your projects into Solution Folders, you can right click on a folder to build all the projects within it.

*(I have a 100-project solution (yup!) where I've got a custom build configuration which builds nothing, so I can select which items to build manually.)*

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading/unloading them? Is it a performance issue?

I recently worked on a project with many projects, each with their own tests. The problem we faced was that building the solution with all these projects could take 15 minutes. Most of the team development time was spent in a small group of 3 or 4 projects and we rarely changed some projects that were dependencies (such as web services). To increase productivity, we created a new solution that only included these 3 or 4 projects (and their test projects) and would spend most of our time in the "Small" solution instead of the "Full" solution.

One gotcha about this arrangement is that if you perform a refactoring with a large impact such as a method signature change or base interface change, you have to remember to perform that refactoring in the "Full" solution or you will find some delightful surprises when you attempt a build later on.

Comment: It's not a performance issue. I just have miscellaneous tests that don't have anything to do with each other. I just like to keep them all together for easy reference under one solution.